# Borel measures on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Consider the following text from Folland's text "Real analysis":

[image]

In theorem 1.15, I'm a bit confused:  How is $\mu_0$ defined on sets of the form $(a, \infty)$? Don't we need to say how $\mu_0$ is defined on sets of that form? I.e. it seems $\mu_0$ is not defined on all of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: $(a_j,b_k]$ is **not** an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$.

Comment: That's my point! The proposition says that $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$ and $(a,\infty)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, so how is $\mu_0((a, \infty))$ defined?

Comment: What is a "premeasure", at  least according to Folland?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure The domain of the pre-measure is an algebra in Folland's book. Basically it is a "measure on an algebra".

Comment: But if $(a,\infty)$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$ then it is irrelevant. A natural definition should probably be $\mu( (a,\infty) )=\underset{x\to \infty}{\lim} F(x)- F(a)$, though.

Comment: But it is in $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: I guess that’s an omission in the book. When you define the Lebesgue measure usually the premeaure is given by the sums of the lengths of the intervals so that on $(a, +\infty)$ is $+\infty$. In the general proposition you cite, you could fill the gap in the book by seeing $(a, +\infty)=\bigcup^{\infty} (a, n]$ and then taking the infinite sum.

Comment: I think it is a typo in the book.

Comment: At the top of the page, Folland says that $(a,b],\ (a,\infty),\ $ and $\emptyset$ are the building blocks and even $a$ is allowed to be $-\infty.$ Since $F$ is increasing right continuous, there is no problem with the definition, in the extended real numbers. For example, if $a=-\infty,$ then $\mu_0(a,b])=F(b)-\lim_{t\to -\infty}F(t)$ and this limit is guaranteed to exist. I think Folland's terse style leaves this for the reader to figure out.

Comment: @ggeolier I'm not sure the infinite sum helps, since these sets $(a,n]$ are not disjoint!

Comment: Yes you are right what I meant was $(a,n]\cup (n,n+1]\cup ...$

Comment: That boils down to saying $F(\infty)-F(a)$ where $F(\infty) = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ I think.